# Why would a portlet need to change the character encoding?

Tags: api, portlet

I'm wondering why a portlet would need to change the character encoding? If it's included in a page, the page should already have a character encoding. I don't see what a browser is supposed to do when a portlet uses a different one.

Follow-up question: why does the portlet 2.0 api contradict itself when it comes to character encoding? There's one place where it says portlets aren't allowed to change the character encoding, but later it shows you how.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the specification doesn't say that you can change the character encoding of a portlet.

Section *12.7.1 Setting the Response Character Set* of the 2.0 spec says that the encoding of a ResourceResponse can be changed. But that is a different thing than changing the portlet encoding, because the resource responses are sent independently from the page containing the portlets.